# How to run a command in C++ without a CMD window showing up?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

So, to be more specific, I want to make a C++ program (Windows) that can execute a command without anything being displayed to the user.

No CMD window, No Command Output.

I would show my previous attempts, but it's not really anything useful, I just used the `system()` function to execute a command. I need to do the same, but without a popup window.

Comment: I typed up an answer below. But it really comes down to this: **what are you really trying to do?**

Answer (score 2):

`system()` uses `CreateProcess()` to run `cmd.exe /C <command>`.  You have no control over the console window that may be created.

Use `CreateProcess()` directly instead, so you can specify the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag, and/or set its input `STARTUPINFO::wShowWindow` field to `SW_HIDE`.